# C++ How do I make a program detect my keystrokes globally?

Tags: c++, windows

I'm making a program and I want it to detect whenever I press F6 and then call an if statement. This should work globally, not just when I'm focused on my program. How can I do that?

Comment: What OS is this for? There's nothing for this in standard C++, so you'll need to use OS-specific APIs.

Answer (score 6):

Since you're on Windows, you can set up a keyboard hook using [`SetWindowsHookEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with `WH_KEYBOARD` or `WH_KEYBOARD_LL`. Then process keypresses in your matching [KeyboardProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644984%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [LowLevelKeyboardProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644985%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, and filter out any F6 presses. Make sure you call [`CallNextHookEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644974%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for any non-F6 keypress, since failing to call `CallNextHookEx` will "eat" the keyboard message.

You'll want to do this in a DLL; you'll need both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of the DLL, since 32-bit apps can only be injected with a 32-bit DLL and 64-bit apps can only be injected with a 64-bit DLL.

---

You could also try something based around [`RegisterHotKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This is somewhat safer than a hook, although if another application calls `RegisterHotKey` and specifies F6 before yours does, you won't be able to register the hotkey.

Since you don't want any extra modifiers on your hotkey, the call would look something like this:

```
RegisterHotKey(myHwnd, 1, 0, VK_F6);
```

where `myHwnd` is the HWND of your window (or optionally `nullptr` if you'd rather process the `WM_HOTKEY` messages in your message loop), `1` is the identifier of the hotkey and can be whatever int you like, `0` specifies no modifier keys (Ctrl, Alt, Windows key, etc.), and `VK_F6` is the virtual keycode for F6.

Comment: I don't think you need a DLL for `KeyboardProc`, the description states that the event is delivered as a message to **your** message loop.

Comment: @MSalters Are you referring to this bit in the `SetWindowsHookEx` docs? *Be aware that the WH_MOUSE, WH_KEYBOARD, WH_JOURNAL*, WH_SHELL, and low-level hooks can be called on the thread that installed the hook rather than the thread processing the hook.* I don't fully understand that bit; are you saying the hook callback would be treated as a normal Windows message and left in your normal message loop, as opposed to the usual hook behavior of calling the specified callback function? Would a callback function even be necessary, then?

Comment: I suppose for backwards API compatibility. Microsoft is quite clear that these hook functions are NOT good design. "Debugging only". It's a surprise that the UAC cleanup around Vista kept them. From a security perspective, you don't want random DLLs in every process.

Comment: I'd be more surprised if MS got rid of the hook functions, at least the keyboard and mouse ones. Such hooks seem fairly common, and I don't know what could be used to replace them (although thanks for reminding me of `RegisterHotKey` while I was trying to think of a substitute for a keyboard hook).

Comment: Yes, they're unfortunately in common use. So that's why I suspect that the implementation has been cleaned up instead of removed: call the hook in the hooking process and use messages to deliver the actual event. It wouldn't surprise me if `DefWindowProc` is on the call stack of your hook function.

Comment: If I use `RegisterHotKey` should I call `UnregisterHotKey` before exiting ?

Answer (score 1):

The function you need is `RegisterHotKey(VK_F6 ...)`, and it will cause `WM_HOTKEY` to be sent. You'll therefore need a Windows message loop.